# Interface Downcasting

Tags: c#, .net, interface, downcast

Please suppose I have the following extension method in order to be able to force evaluation of an `IEnumerable`:

```
public static List<T> EvaluateNow<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (collection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    }
    else
    {
        return (collection.ToList());
    }
}
```

I would like to ask if there is any point in having `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>` as this method's return type (i.e., downcasting to an interface) in order to tie neither it nor its dependencies to a particular implementation (even if the return value will always actually be a `List`).

Comment: For this particular function I don't think so. Also I don't think its worth having a extension method like this that just runs `.ToList()`

Comment: IList<T> allows one of many implementations, one being List<T>. If that's not important to support future change in structures, then no.

Comment: However ity is a good habit to get into. One day you WILL need to support future change that you did not anticipate ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ***always*** a good idea to use interfaces in situations like this rather than classes.
The reasons why are too numerous to get into here, but for example, it greatly increass flexibility as any class just needs to implement the interface `IList<T>` to be assignable to the return value of this function. Classes will implement this (or other) interfaces without subclassing List (or equivalent).
In general you want to use the 'lowest' heirachical interface that fits the requirements. In this case, you could consider ICollection, or even IEnumerable instead of IList.

It is irrelevant what class instance you return from the function, as only 'the interface' is returned, so it can be assigned to any class implementing that interface (again, max flexibilty?)

Often a function returning some IEnumerable object will mostly be used inside a foreach loop.

Comment: Well, Microsoft apparently decided that `ToList()` should return `List<T>` rather than `IList<T>`

Answer (score 1):

An extension method can only be called on an instance. Which means that `collection` can never be `null` in your method.

So... as written your method has the exact same behavior the extension method `IEnumerable.ToList` so I don't see any point.

It would be useful if its return type was `IList` as Aaron explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620422/interface-downcasting/7620498#7620498).

Why does `IEnumerable.ToList` not already return a `IList` would be a good question for the library designers.

Comment: Have you ever tried `IList<int> newList = null; int newInt = newList.First();`? The compiler won't complain when you apply the extension method `First()` (defined on `System.Linq`), but when you run the program you will certainly get an exception, so I would say that extension methods can indeed be called on `null` references.

Comment: @DotNetStudent indeed I stand corrected. But the behavior would still be same..throw `ArgumentNullException`. I will modify my answer.

Comment: But `ToList()` internally throws the same exception as your method does, which means that just like @Hemal says you are just creating an alias for `ToList()`

Comment: @DotNetStudent...when newList.First() throws exception it is not from inside the `First` method but at the call-site. Nevertheless, I think you helped improved my answer.